# Is running long cron jobs from command line faster than http?

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

I have many PHP scripts scheduled in cron which take about a minute to run.

They currently are run by loading it through HTTP, will it make a significant difference if I try to run them through the command line in cron instead?

Comment: Yes it is faster and you can avoid browser time outs.

Comment: If it is faster, it would only be marginally faster. However not running them over HTTP will reduce the strain on the webserver (since it won't have to handle the requests) and ensure the tasks still run even if the webserver is down/at capacity.